# java unit testing a local scoped string

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit

there is an internal dependency in my method :

```
String myString ... //do some stuff to string determined my method parameters
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(myString);
```

myString is local method scope, and is not returned - is there anyway to test what myString looks like via a unit test ? Other than injecting it as an external depedency and creating a mock of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would extract the exec part in a collaborator, and mock this collaborator:

```
public interface ProgramLauncher {
    Process exec(String command);
}

...

@Test
public void test() {
    ProgramLauncher mockLauncher = mock(ProgramLauncher.class);
    YourClass underTest = new YourClass(mockLauncher);
    underTest.callMethod();
    verify(mockLauncher).exec("the expected command");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather extract

> //do some stuff to string determined my method parameters

to separate method and just test this method.